# Transforming one rectangle into another

Tags: php, image-processing, affinetransform

I have image that's a rectangle `(a, b)-(c, d)` and I need to transform it into another rectangle `(e, f)-(g, h)`.

The transformation can have **translation**, **scaling** and **rotation**. My linear algebra is quite rusty but I am guessing I need to derive an affine transform matrix unless there is a better way.

I am working in PHP so I need to know how to compute the appropriate parameters to imageaffine().

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oleg, if you have 4 points this transformations is perspective. For affine transformation, three points are enough.
You can try using Imagemagick. 
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Comment: This seems to do what I want it to do. Not PHP but I can call it from PHP and it beats re-inventing this from scratch for my purposes.